# Using a letter's float value to compare?

Tags: c++, loops, floating-point, char

Say I'm entering numbers to a float, and want to exit the loop when a q is entered. I thought I could check what value was assigned when the 'q' was entered, then compare for in the loop, but floats seem to be a little imprecise so this doesent work:

```
int main() {

    float input;
    bool exit = true;
    do{
        cin >> input;
        if (input == -1.07974e+08) {
            exit=false;
            continue;
        }
        input = 0;
       } while (exit);
```

The only way I can think to make this work (as in, check for a letter when entering numbers) is to save each input as a string, compare it, and use something like atof() each time i need to work with them. But it seems very inefficient to run the parser for every input, when the letter is supposed to be an exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: Incidentally, it's jarring to have a variable named `exit` whose value should be `false` to exit the loop. The logic really should be the other way around: `true` means exit the loop, and the test becomes `while (!exit)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure you only have one character to worry about, you can just use `peek()` to take a look at the next character without actually consuming it:

```
if(cin.peek() == 'q')
{
    exit=false;
    continue;
}
```

If it's more complex than that, then you'll have to first read a string, then parse it.

Don't forget, reading a float already involves parsing it, so the main difference is the intermediate copy into a string, which shouldn't be too bad since you're probably not copying a lot of characters. Plus, if you reuse the same string instance every time, its buffer will be reused as well.

Oh, also, you can use the handy little function `std::stof` to parse the string into a float.

Comment: Um, it goes into a loop whenever I enter a character, something goes wrong whenever the letter is stored, but not sure what. This seems like the way to go, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
    int main() {

        float input;
        char end = 'y';
        bool exit = true;
        do{
            cin >> input;
            cout << "Do you want to continue? y/n ";
            cin >> end;
            if (end == 'n') exit = false;
            input = 0;
           } while (exit);
}
```